# Drawing A Rotated Path2D Object on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, html5-canvas

I have a canvas where i want to draw a rotated svg.

In order to achieve this, i created a Path2D object and used the context.fill() option to draw the svg.

Moreover, I used context.translate(x , y) inorder to position the svg.

Now, the issue i how to rotate this?

I found some solutions where it stated that first use `context.translate(x , y)` to set the transformation point and then use `context.rotate(deg)` to rotate.

Now, both the translate are in conflict.

Here is the code that I have tried so far. This code rotates the svg element. But from its top right corner. I want it to be rotated from center:

Codepen link - https://codepen.io/asiancat54x/pen/jOwyeaR

Here is the code snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>

    <script>
        const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")

        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

        const path = new Path2D()

        path.addPath(new Path2D('M 25.214844 0.0664062 C 23.191406 0.332031 20.324219 1.554688 17.460938 3.378906 C 15.777344 4.441406 14.132812 5.679688 12.535156 7.082031 C 11.585938 7.917969 11.566406 7.929688 11.273438 7.929688 C 11.140625 7.929688 10.589844 7.824219 10.046875 7.691406 C 9.230469 7.492188 8.996094 7.457031 8.628906 7.472656 C 7.753906 7.519531 7.9375 7.367188 3.777344 11.53125 C 1.277344 14.035156 0.0546875 15.300781 0.0273438 15.402344 C -0.0351562 15.664062 0.0429688 15.851562 0.253906 15.941406 C 0.351562 15.988281 1.636719 16.222656 3.089844 16.445312 C 6.042969 16.90625 6.269531 16.917969 6.859375 16.648438 C 7.042969 16.5625 7.28125 16.429688 7.378906 16.355469 C 7.484375 16.273438 7.632812 16.207031 7.707031 16.207031 C 7.808594 16.207031 8.582031 16.949219 10.773438 19.140625 C 12.378906 20.75 13.703125 22.113281 13.703125 22.164062 C 13.703125 22.21875 13.636719 22.335938 13.5625 22.429688 C 13.34375 22.683594 13.132812 23.152344 13.054688 23.542969 C 12.984375 23.886719 12.996094 24.015625 13.402344 26.621094 C 13.636719 28.113281 13.851562 29.421875 13.878906 29.535156 C 13.945312 29.761719 14.082031 29.851562 14.355469 29.851562 C 14.527344 29.851562 14.851562 29.539062 18.292969 26.097656 C 21.648438 22.761719 22.066406 22.324219 22.210938 22.007812 C 22.496094 21.398438 22.492188 21.167969 22.183594 19.863281 C 22.027344 19.191406 21.925781 18.660156 21.949219 18.589844 C 21.972656 18.519531 22.285156 18.136719 22.644531 17.726562 C 26.28125 13.621094 28.867188 9.066406 29.644531 5.394531 C 29.792969 4.734375 29.808594 4.5 29.8125 3.613281 C 29.8125 2.660156 29.808594 2.5625 29.660156 2.117188 C 29.285156 1.003906 28.535156 0.320312 27.402344 0.0820312 C 26.996094 -0.0078125 25.792969 -0.0195312 25.214844 0.0664062 Z M 23.464844 4.5625 C 25.449219 5.203125 26.210938 7.632812 24.957031 9.285156 C 24.0625 10.472656 22.503906 10.855469 21.179688 10.199219 C 20.101562 9.675781 19.472656 8.65625 19.472656 7.460938 C 19.472656 6.601562 19.753906 5.910156 20.371094 5.304688 C 21.183594 4.488281 22.367188 4.203125 23.464844 4.5625 Z M 23.464844 4.5625'))

        path.addPath(new Path2D("M 6.871094 18.929688 C 5.667969 20.199219 4.289062 22.570312 3.445312 24.839844 C 3.039062 25.953125 2.84375 27.003906 3.027344 27.183594 C 3.113281 27.273438 3.285156 27.210938 4.402344 26.683594 C 4.914062 26.441406 5.910156 26.019531 6.613281 25.746094 C 8.675781 24.933594 9.160156 24.6875 9.96875 24.0625 C 10.480469 23.65625 11.269531 22.910156 11.328125 22.777344 C 11.351562 22.714844 11.335938 22.589844 11.28125 22.480469 C 11.226562 22.378906 10.375 21.472656 9.371094 20.476562 C 7.671875 18.792969 7.527344 18.65625 7.339844 18.65625 C 7.175781 18.65625 7.089844 18.707031 6.871094 18.929688 Z M 6.871094 18.929688 "))

        var rotation = 0

        canvas.width = innerWidth

        canvas.height = innerHeight

        const animate = () => {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate)

            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0 , 0 , 0 , 0.1)"

            ctx.fillRect(0 , 0 , canvas.width , canvas.height)

            ctx.fillStyle = "white"

            ctx.translate(70 , 70)

            ctx.rotate(rotation)

            rotation += 0.1

            ctx.fill(path)

            ctx.resetTransform()
        }

        animate()


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd read about how transformations work in computer graphic (transformation matrices).

Here's an article explaining it thoroughly:
https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations

Your issue as you stated is where the svg is rotated from - the `transformation origin` is not the center of the svg.

To change the transformation origin you can apply a translation *after* the rotation (Read to article to understand why).

```
ctx.rotate(rotation)
ctx.translate(-15 , -15)
```

I played around with it and this hit the spot although I'd recommend finding the actual thing that causes the origin to shift in the first place. (avoid using `magic numbers` - especially when applying transformations).

Comment: Can you show me an example or edit my code so that I understand this more clearly

Comment: I added an example, just add the translate(-15,-15) after the rotation.

Comment: Oh yes, I have implemented that wrong. Thanks for your answer. +1 vote + Accepted Solution ;)

Comment: I also had this problem. Can you explain why you wrote ```ctx.translate(-15 , -15)```

Comment: Basically transformations work in reverse, so translating "after" a rotation move the object before the rotation is applied - therefore changing the axis of rotation. -15 is the just a magic number I found. It is advised to find the reason a translation is required and then use these numbers to apply transformations. e.g. the default axis is 0,0 but since the svg is transformed by definition (the path's axis is not 0,0) you need to move it by x,y to match it with 0,0 before rotating.